# Notify Slack send Array

Tags: laravel, notify

im trying to send some values from a DB with Notify to Slack. Somehow every time I load my Website the only message I get is "Array" and not the data from the DB.

This is my Notifications .php

```
class InventoryReStock extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($reorder)
    {
      $this->reorder = $reorder;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['slack'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toSlack($notifiable)
    {
      return (new SlackMessage)
            ->content([$this->reorder]);
    }
```

This is the function that Im using on my controller to get the data form the Db

```
public function index()
    {
        //shows all the products in the database in an overview
        $products = Product::all()->toArray();

        $reord = Product::select('Product_Name')->where('Number_Runs', '<=', '5')->get();
        $reorder = json_decode(json_encode($reord), true);
        Notification::route('slack', 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/..../...../......')->notify(new InventoryReStock($reorder));

        return view('products.lab_inventory_overview', compact('products', 'reorder'));
    }
```

and this is my User.php

```
public function routeNotificationForSlack($notification)
   {
       Return 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/..../...../......';
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found a solution . Just converting the array to string makes it work.

$reorder =  implode(', ', array_flatten($reorde));